# Similar recursive case, different run time?

Tags: java, runtime

The first one's run time is O(log n) which I know is the run time for most recursive cases.

```
int happy (int n, int m) { 
   if (n < 10) return n; 
   else if (n < 100) 
      return happy (n - 2, m); 
   else 
      return happy (n/2, m); 
}
```

However, the second recursive case's run time is O(n)

```
int silly(int n, int m) { 
   if (n < 1) return m; 
   else if (n < 10) 
     return silly(n/2, m); 
   else 
     return silly(n - 2, m); 
}
```

Can anyone explain why? I would really appreciate that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function reduces `n` much quicker than the second. `happy` divides `n` by 2 until it gets below 100. `silly` *subtracts* 2 until it gets below 10.

`happy` is O(log n) because it takes log_2(n) steps until it gets down below 100, then at most 50 steps to get below 1.

`silly` is O(n) because it takes n/2 steps to get below 100, then at most 5 steps to get below 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any strategies for figuring out the run time?

Comment: That is not a simplistic subject. The goal is to try and figure out, given `n` inputs or an input of size `n`, how many meaningful/significant _operations_ (nebulously defined) the algorithm executes in order to complete. In the case of these two functions, I calculated how many times the function will call itself until the base case is reached.